# "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" in JSF project

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsf, jsf-2

I have a `html` template which do not throw any exception, for that check I'm using `Google Chrome Developer Tools`, after move from html to `JSF 2` project I got this message in my `.xhtml` page:

[image]

This is the whole refered code:

```
if ($('.chart').length) {

  var size = 240;

  if($('html').width() < 778){ size = 175 }

    $('.chart').easyPieChart({
      animate: 2000,
      barColor: "#02b6eb",
      lineCap: "square",
      lineWidth: 8,
      scaleColor: false,
      size: size,
      trackColor: "#bfc8d1",
    });
}
```

Which works in the `html` project but not into `JSF` project.
I really do not work with jQuery, so any help would be very helpful.

Comment: It looks like either jQuery or the plugin easyPieChart isn't loaded when this code is reached. Did you import jQuery and the plugin?

Comment: Yes I did. But something I notice now it was that the order of these imports matters. I had created a default `<ui:compostion>` for the `head` and import the differentials below, but it seems that I cant do that. So I create another `<ui:compostion>` specific for this page and it works fine! Thanks for the help @YoannM, your comment was very helpful.

Comment: With another page now the problem keep happening..

Comment: Are you sure it's the same problem? If it's the same, then the solution might be similar.